# Sans-Serif and Monospace font matching Gentium (pdflatex)

Tags: fonts, typewriter, sans-serif

Since I could not find a typography / font SX I figure this question might be suited best here (also I want to use the fonts for a LaTeX document).

I find the [Gentium](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gentium/) font visually attractive and I want to use it for my bachelor thesis. The one thing I'm wondering about is which sans-serif and monospace font match best (from a typographer's point of view) with Gentium. I'm thinking about setting the section titles etc. in serif, too -- that would lower the needs for a sans-serif counterpart. But a good typewriter font is needed anyway.

I've already had a look at the available [Typewriter](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) and [Sans-Serif](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html) fonts but since I'm not typography expert I'm not quite sure what to look for.

Comment: You might have success at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on graphicdesign SE. (It is about which fonts to use and not how to use them, and asks specifically for typographic expertise which is more likely found there.)